# Can I use Mason Sand under Pavers?

Tags: patio, pavers, retaining-wall

I put an inch layer of mason sand down over a compacted base of process, and am about to lay large concrete pavers (18"x18", 12"x18", and 9" square) down.

Now I'm reading that I should have used concrete sand.

Will mason sand work ok?  I'm noticing that when dry it compresses and spreads very easily when I lay the large pavers down.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Coarser sand is better.

Concrete sand would work much better than mason sand.

When I used to do pavers we would use crusher dust.

That being said, it's a patio and not a driveway or a road, so I don't think I would be overly concerned if I had already put down mason's sand.